# linux :counting the occurence of 1's in each column

Tags: linux

Linux :counting the occurrence of `1's` in each column

i have a file with the following content

```
 0       0       1       0       0

 0       0       1       1       1

 0       1       1       1       0

 1       0       1       0       0
```

Now, i want to count the `1's` in each column and need to write it into a file along with it's column  number.

so what i expected is ,

```
 1        1

 2        1

 3        4

 4        2

 5        1
```

where the first column stands for the column position (from 1 to 5 in the given example)

and the second column is the count of `1's` respective column

A change in my output requirement:

5      1

4      1

3      4

2      2

1      1

Need to print the Column number in reverse order(5 insread od 1 etc)

Comment: You can't do that with Linux. Linux is just an operating system. What programming language are we talking about?

Comment: "so what i expected is XYZ" - why did you expect *anything* when you have done *nothing?*

Comment: You should show us what you have tried, this way you don't get the answers you are looking for. Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't like when people expect somebody else to solve their vaguely defined problems.

Answer (score 0):

awk is better tool for this:

```
awk 'NF>0{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i==1) a[NR]++;} 
     END{for(i=1; i<=length(a); i++) print i, a[i]}' file
```

**EDIT 1:** To count 1's in each column:

```
awk 'NF>0{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i==1) a[i]++;}
     END{for(i=1; i<=length(a); i++) print i, a[i]}' file
```

**EDIT 2:** To count 1's in each column, printing in reverse order:

```
awk 'NF>0{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i==1) a[i]++;}
     END{for(i=length(a); i>=1; i--) print i, a[i]}' file
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, but a small change what you have given is number of 1's in each row, but what I am looking for is number of 1's in each column. Can you modify script accordingly please?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to change the numbering in reverse order?

Comment: Pipe the awk command with `sort -nrk 2` like `awk 'NF>0{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i==1) a[i]++;} END{for(i=1; i<=length(a); i++) print i, a[i]}' file | sort -nrk 2`

Comment: Sorry, i don't want to sort the output.Actually i just want to make the numbering of columns given in the result to be reversed. Keeping the a[i] value same